# How to get the onclick "attribute event" return value in "property event"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Consider this code sample :

```
<a href="some url" onclick="confirm('ok to proceed ?')">bla</a>`

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
              $("a").live("click", function (event) {
                    // In that function, I want to get 
                    // the "confirm" return value                  
               });
</script>
```

It is possible to get this return value without modifying the DOM?

Comment: Thanks to the answers below but my problem is precisely to combine attribute event (onclick) and property event (onClick), without modifiying explicitaly the onclick attribute :
See my jquery plugin : http://garage.pimentech.net/scripts_doc_jquery_jframe/ 
>>>>> I want to stop the event propagation if onclick attribute returns false...

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="some url" onclick="var myVar = confirm('ok to proceed ?')">bla</a>
```

If I remember correctly, that should work. You would then have access to `myVar` in your jQuery block like you would have access to any other Javascript variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, the value is not stored anywhere for you to access. The only way to get that value is to move it to a jQuery handled click event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The removeAttr removes the original "onclick" attribute
    $("a").removeAttr('onclick').live("click", function (event) {
       var ret = confirm('ok to proceed ?');
       // Do what you want here because `ret` has the return 
       // value from the `confirm` call.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly add the word "return", like this:

```
onclick="return confirm('ok to proceed?')"
```

EDIT: my initial reply was BS, here's what I got to work finally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        var stuff = confirm('ok?');
        if (stuff) {
        alert('was ok, stuff=' + stuff);
        }
    else {
        alert('was not ok, stuff=' + stuff);
        }
    });
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm maybe this is it, too. Where does the return value get stored? The jQuery `event` parameter passed to the anonymous function?

Comment: iirc the event gets cancelled if the user clicks cancel, so I'm not sure the JQuery code would execute.

Answer (score -1):

`` getValueConfirm` ``

var isConfirm = false;

         function confirmDialog(){
            isconfirm = confirm('ok to proceed ?');
         }
    $(document).ready(function() {
              $("a").live("click", function (event) {
                    alert(isconfirm);// your value that you want get it         
               });
  });