# html control with image to get the click event using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, anchor

In our application we are using set of images as slides. If we click one image we want to get the id of the  in the same page. i have tried by using the following code.

code:
  HTML:

```
<a id="100" href="#"> <img scr="..."/> </a>
...
```

JQUERY code:

```
$("div.alb a").click(function() {

        });
```

Problem:

```
Without href="#" the click event is not working.

I want to get the id by clicking the image without using server control.

Without using server control is it possible to achieve this task.
```

Geetha.

Comment: maybe this helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976118/how-to-get-the-onclick-attribute-event-return-value-in-property-event
or this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910850/jquery-assign-onclick-for-li-from-a-link

Comment: XML id's can't start with numbers. Or at least it's invalid. Just a heads up.

Comment: Hi, It should not redirect to other page. Just i want to get the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<img src="..." id="i100"/>
```

js (jquery):

```
$('img[id]').click(function(){
  var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
  return false;
});
```

otherwise, if you cant modify your html-code just add 'return false' to prevent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me without using herf.

You can check it out here.

http://jsbin.com/uroke

I can't get a image to show up when using jsbin not sure why though.

```
$(function()
  {
      $("a").click(function()
      {
          var test = $(this).attr('id');
          alert(test);
      });
  });
```